# Match fields within one data frame with column names in another data frame

Tags: dataframe, rstudio

I have two data frames. In the last column ("Bill") in the first data frame, I want to apply a function (fixed price + Quantity*price/qty). In order to apply the function, R should match the values in the first column of df1 to the column names of df2.

I have solved the problem by creating a function and several ifelse statements, but I would want to use a statement that automatically matches the values in df1 with the column names in df2. The data set that I have contains more than 2 million rows and I would need to apply the same rationale into building other similar functions. It would be nice to use something that does not require a loop or takes too long to process.

[image: see what the data frame should look like here]

Comment: it would be appreciated if you could post code that makes this dataframes, so it makes the process reproducible.

Comment: Please only use the `rstudio` tag if your question concerns the RStudio code editor. You wouldn't use a `pen-and-paper` tag when asking a question about grammar!

Answer (score 1):

```
### Set up your data frames like so ###
Code <- c("a1", "a2", "c3", "a1")
Name <- c("Dan", "David", "Anna", "Lisa")
Quantity <- c(30, 12, 10, 10)

df1 <- as.data.frame(cbind("Code" = Code, "Name" = Name, "Quantity" = Quantity), stringsAsFactors = F)
df1$Quantity <- as.numeric(df1$Quantity)

fixed_price <- c(12, 5, 23)
price_per_qty <- c(1, 4, 7)

df2 <- as.data.frame(rbind("fixed_price" = fixed_price, "price_per_qty" = price_per_qty))
colnames(df2) <- c("a1", "a2", "c3")

### Combine dataframe 1 and 2 into a single dataframe ###

# Code below pulls individual columns from df2 based on the 
# index provided by the "Code" column in df1, transposes them
# so they'll line up with df1, then column binds them to df1
df3 <- cbind(df1, t(df2[,df1$Code]))

# the bill is calculated simply enough
bill <- df3[4] + df3[3] * df3[5]
colnames(bill) <- "bill"
# Finally, output the results as you wanted
cbind(df3, bill)
```

Comment: Nice way of using the cbind function and indexing it with the df1$Code

Comment: This was very useful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So I have a fairly similar answer to graggsd, but here is what worked for me. I merged two data frames based on the key word "Code" and then combined it into the big data frame into combined_data. I then used a function which I think is what you defined above and then passed the respective data frames through it.

```
df2 <- t(data.frame(c(12,1),c(5,4),c(23,7)))
rownames(df2) <- c("a1","a2","c3")
test <- rownames(df2)
df2 <- cbind.data.frame(df2,test)
colnames(df2) <- c("fixed price","price/qty","Code")


df1 <- data.frame(c("a1","a2","c3","a1"), c("Dan","David","Anna","Lisa"),c(30,12,10,10))
colnames(df1) <- c("Code","Name","Quantity")


combined_data <- dplyr::inner_join(df1,df2, by = "Code")



f1 <- function(x,y,z){
  x + y * z
}
bill <- f1(combined_data[,4],combined_data[,3],combined_data[,5])

finalDataSet <- cbind.data.frame(combined_data,bill)
```

The final data set:

```
   Code  Name Quantity fixed price price/qty bill
1   a1   Dan       30          12         1   42
2   a2 David       12           5         4   53
3   c3  Anna       10          23         7   93
4   a1  Lisa       10          12         1   22
```